# Change icon size on mouse over - (FontAwesome + Bootstrap)

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I want to display a 2x icon size on mouse over  element.

I'm using FontAwesome with bootstrap.
I have a List like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href ="#"><i class="icon-inbox"></i> Inbox<a/></li>
    <li><a href ="#"><i class="icon-print"></i> print<a/></li>
    ....
</ul>
```

I want to add "icon-2x" fontawesome css class, on mouse over element, to display a larger icon, and remove that class on mouse leave.

I want it to look like the FontAwesome homepage examples. like this:

[image]

I tried finding  elemets with jQuery to add the css class, but a couldn't do it.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: How is your class done (icon-inbox or icon-print)? Could you show the css code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why don't you just use CSS `:hover`?

```
li i[class^="icon-"] { font-size:12px; }
li:hover i[class^="icon-"] { font-size:24px; }
```

FontAwesome uses a font for the icons, so to double the icon size you simply double the font size. Of course you'd also need to cater for padding, margins and whatever else to ensure the icon stays relative to the text beside it.

If you still want to use jQuery to add a new class:

```
$('li').hover(function() {
    $('i[class^="icon-"]', this).addClass('icon-2x');
}, function() {
    $('i[class^="icon-"]', this).removeClass('icon-2x');
})
```

Comment: Excellent!, both ways work properly. Finally I'll use :hover css.
Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest to use CSS scale (I'm using it for links on my page with FontAwesome):

```
a:hover i { transform: scale(2); }
```

It won't move the elements which are next to the icon (for example the other text) what change font size cause.

**UPDATE**

See the example how it works with FontAwesome on the footer of my home page: http://pnowy.github.io/about/

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to have a animated switch you will need to use javascript. But you could achieve this without it by doing this

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="image" href ="#"></a> <p>Long story</p></li>
</ul>
```

And then stylew it like this

```
.image{
    float:left;
    display:block;
    background:url('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/deleket/sleek-xp-software/256/Yahoo-Messenger-icon.png');
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-size:50px 50px;
}
li p{
    line-height:50px;
    vertical-align:center;
}
li:hover p{
    line-height:70px;
}
li:hover .image{
    width:70px;
    height:70px;
    background-size:70px 70px;
}
```

You can see a fiddle here [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/echvZ/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the font size to the :before pseudo element.

```
li:hover i:before {
    font-size: 24px /*or whatever*/
}
```

See:  http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/